# White context menu (copy/paste)

Tags: android, android-edittext, uri, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to be able to copy text from EditText boxes. This is what it looks like now, I do not get an option (in the top bar) to copy the highlighted text. How do I enable it the easiest way?

[image]

Comment: maybe you have and it might be white  :)

Comment: Dude it worked!! How do I get it to become visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed icons in my case, from theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.ituTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ....
       
        <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/cut</item>
        <item name="actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/cut</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/copy</item>
        <item name="actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/copy</item>
        <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/paste</item>
        <item name="actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/paste</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/select_all</item>
        <item name="actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/select_all</item>
         ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

copy, cut, paste, select_all

[image: copy][image: cut][image: paste][image: select_all]

Comment: You can get gray icons from icons8.com

Comment: Great thanks I will try it later and let you know how it works out! :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Vote up my question so I can vote up your answer.